# InstallShield 2010 Basic MSI Project -Adding a dialog to execute sequence

Tags: customdialog, installshield-2010, basic-msi

How to add a custom dialog to the execute sequence of a Basic MSI project in InstallShield 2010?

I want this dialog to be shown when installer is run directly as a .EXE file or
from the command line MSIEXEC.EXE with basic ui command line argument

Is this possible to do, if so how?

Thanks in advance

Raghu.

Answer (score 0):

Create your dialog in the User Interface view. Then, depending on whether you want it to be part of the wizard panels, or standalone, either:

- Edit the Control Events of the Next and Back buttons to have NewDialog actions that point to your new dialog, and from it to its new surrounding pages, or
- Add to the InstallUISequence a custom action that references your new dialog, and ensure that it has a Control Event action that will close it.

Chances are most dialogs will be better as part of the series of wizard panels, so I would suggest going with the first option.